# ajax doesn't load my php file in the background

Tags: php, ajax

I'm having a problem with my ajax call. I'm submitting some info via php to mySQL, the submission part works perfectly, it's adding the data to the database, but the ajax function isn't loading that php in the background, it's loading it in the window and showing the php file results.

Here's the HTML code.

```
<form action="upload.php" class="addItem" method="post">
      Firstname:<br><input type="text" class="firstname" name="firstname" /><br>
      Lastname:<br><input type="text" class="lastname" name="lastname" /><br>
      Age:<br><input type="text" class="age" name="age" /><br>
      Photo:<br><input type="file" name="image" accept="image/jpeg" /><br><br>
      <input type="submit" class="submitItem" value="Add Row" />
  </form>
  <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
  </div>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submitItem").click(function(){
    // Start AJAX send
      jQuery.ajax({
        // Enter below the full path to your "send" php file
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",   
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
          // If form submission is successful
          if ( html == 1 ) {
            $('.successMessage').show(200);
            $('.successMessage').delay(2000).hide();
          }
          // Double check if maths question is correct
          else {
            $('.errorMessage').show(200);
            $('.errorMessage').delay(2000).hide();
          }
        }
      });
      });
    });

  </script>
```

Here's the PHP code

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['firstname'];
$surname = $_POST['lastname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];

if(($name === "") || ($surname === "") || ($age === "")){
    echo "please fill in all fields";
} else {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    if ($sql) { echo "1"; }
    else{echo "error";}
    }

    mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handler needs to `return false;` to instruct the browser not to do its regular submission action.

(Also, you should really consider using the `submit` event of the form, rather than the `click` event of the button.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("form.addItem").submit(function(){
    // Start AJAX send
    jQuery.ajax({
      // ... your parameters ...
    });
    return false;     
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks Amber, This is just a test run, but I'll switch it over to .submit, I'm adding the return false; but it's still loading the php page. Can you maybe indicate to me where you would put it?

Comment: Thanks, I did try that, still does the same...is my HTML form right? I'm suspecting something is wrong there? I've got only jQuery included, I'm quite sure I dont need anything else

Comment: Okay, I figured the Ajax function is being ignored...any idea why?